# Last TableView not executing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been at this for hours. For some reason, the last tableview (neighboursView) in my method isn't executing. Some context: I have 3 tableviews inside of one view controller - the first two load properly, but if tableView == neighboursView never executes.  See code below - any help is appreciated!

**ConnectViewController.h**

```
@interface ConnectViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

- (IBAction)segmentControl:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentControl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *sidetableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myFriendData;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *neighboursView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *friendData;
@property (strong, retain) NSMutableArray *neighbourData;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *friendsView;
```

**ConnectViewController.m**

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"sidebarCell" bundle:nil];
        [self.friendsView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: @"sidebarCell"];
        [self.neighboursView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: @"sidebarCell"];

        nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyFriendTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
        [self.sidetableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: @"MyFriendTableViewCell"];

    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {


        if (tableView == self.friendsView) {
        return [self.friendData count];

        }

        if (tableView == self.neighboursView) {
        return [self.neighbourData count];
        }

        if (tableView == self.sidetableView) {
        return [self.myFriendData count];

        } else {


            return 0; }
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        if (tableView == self.sidetableView) {

            self.sidetableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;


        MyFriendTableViewCell *cell = (MyFriendTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyFriendTableViewCell"];



            NSDictionary *friendsName = [self.myFriendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [[cell friendName] setText:[friendsName objectForKey:@"title"]];

            NSDictionary *friendsBio = [self.myFriendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [[cell friendBio] setText:[friendsBio objectForKey:@"field_friendbio"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"]];


            NSString *profilePath = [[self.myFriendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"field_picture"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];


            [cell.friendPic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePath]];

            NSLog(@"This is profilePath %@",profilePath);

        return cell;

    }

      else if (tableView == self.friendsView)

        {
            self.friendsView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;


            sidebarCell *cell = (sidebarCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sidebarCell"];


            NSDictionary *userName = [self.friendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [[cell username] setText:[userName objectForKey:@"node_title"]];


            NSDictionary *userBio = [self.friendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [[cell userDescription] setText:[userBio objectForKey:@"body"]];

            NSString *profilePath = [[self.friendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"friendphoto"];

            [cell.usermini sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePath]];

            return cell;



        } else if (tableView == self.neighboursView)

        {

     sidebarCell *cell = (sidebarCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sidebarCell"];


            NSDictionary *userName = [self.neighbourData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [[cell username] setText:[userName objectForKey:@"first name"]];

            NSDictionary *userlast = [self.neighbourData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [[cell lastName] setText:[userlast objectForKey:@"last name"]];

            NSDictionary *userBio = [self.neighbourData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [[cell userDescription] setText:[userBio objectForKey:@"userbio"]];



            NSString *profilePath = [[self.neighbourData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photo_path"];

            [cell.usermini sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePath]];

            NSLog(@"This is profilePath %@",profilePath);



            return cell;


        } else {

      UITableViewCell *cell;
     return cell;



    }
    }

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.sidetableView) {


        return 100;

    }

    if (tableView == self.friendsView) {

        return 115;

    }

    if (tableView == self.neighboursView) {

        return 115;

    }

    return 100;
}


    - (IBAction)segmentControl:(id)sender {

        UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
        NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

        switch (selectedSegment)
            {


                case 0:

                    [self.sidetableView setHidden:NO];
                   [self.neighboursView setHidden:YES];
                   [self.friendsView setHidden:YES];

                    NSLog(@"Requests!");

                    break;



                case 1: //FRIENDS MAP VIEW



                    [self.sidetableView setHidden:YES];
                   [self.friendsView setHidden:NO];
                  [self.neighboursView setHidden:YES];


                         NSLog(@"Friends!");

                    break;



                case 2:

                    [self.sidetableView setHidden:YES];
                   [self.neighboursView setHidden:NO];
                  [self.friendsView setHidden:YES];


                         NSLog(@"Neighbours!");
                    break;




            }



        }
```

Comment: Did you call `[self.neighboursView reloadData]` for loading data?

Comment: Where are your table views being initialised? My guess would be an incorrect reference on your nib/storyboard.

Comment: Number of row is executing ? , check height of tableview

Comment: @nynohu Where should I place that?

Comment: You have to check your tableview frame and its heigh may be it will 0 or tableview it self is hidden in that case your code never execute as tableview no visible  rect at all. Please check both height and hidden property.

Comment: Well, so how about the [self.friendsView reloadData]. Even though you didn't call it, you still got the expected results?

Comment: @CodeChanger Checked both - height is fine, and even when I don't hide the table, it still isn't executing.

Comment: You have to put [self.neighboursView reloadData] after you self.neighboursView's data loaded.

Comment: I agree on your point but you have to debug and check at run time what both property value is some time due to some reason system will hide your tableView so please do one thing debug at runtime and check both property.

Comment: @nynohu You nailed this - I needed to reload self.neighboursView inside my DIOSView method up top. YOU ROCK. Lol. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `[self.neighboursView reloadData]` after self.neighboursView's data loaded. It will make `tableView dataSource` methods executed.

One thing I want to point you: If you want to access to an element of array, it does not need address to that element many times as you are doing:

```
NSDictionary *userName = [self.friendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[[cell username] setText:[userName objectForKey:@"node_title"]];


NSDictionary *userBio = [self.friendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[[cell userDescription] setText:[userBio objectForKey:@"body"]];

NSString *profilePath = [[self.friendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"friendphoto"];
```

All of above will be become:

```
NSDictionary *userData = [self.friendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[[cell username] setText:[userData objectForKey:@"node_title"]];
[[cell userDescription] setText:[userData objectForKey:@"body"]];
NSString *profilePath = [userData objectForKey:@"friendphoto"];
```

Of course you should check `[userData objectforkey:]` is not nil before you access data stored in it for avoiding crash.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

You have to register nib for neighboursView also. You register 1 nib for two tables see below

```
Wrong
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"sidebarCell" bundle:nil];
        [self.friendsView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: @"sidebarCell"];
        [self.neighboursView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: @"sidebarCell"];
```

Correct

Create one more nib for `neighboursView` and then register it with `neighboursView` table

```
 UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"sidebarCell" bundle:nil];
        [self.friendsView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: @"sidebarCell"];

UINib *nib1 = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"sidebarCell" bundle:nil];// register your cell here for neighboursView
        [self.neighboursView registerNib:nib1 forCellReuseIdentifier: @"sidebarCell1"];// give your identifier here for neighboursView
```

Comment: I implemented the above code - but I still get a blank table. O_O

Comment: Do you wanna same sidebarCell cell for neighboursView table ?

Comment: Please add sidebarCell1 identifier for neighboursView. Use updated answer. hope it will work for you. and replace this line also `sidebarCell *cell = (sidebarCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sidebarCell1"];`

Comment: @Brittany Are you sure your `[self.neighbourData count]` is greater than 0?

Comment: Yes, I even logged self.neighbourData to be sure! No idea why it's doing this to me lol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138693/discussion-between-dharmbir-singh-and-brittany).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
@property (strong, retain) NSMutableArray *neighbourData;
```

to

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *neighbourData;
```

If that's not it, I still think it might be an incorrect reference in your nib/storyboard file. i.e. you linked the table in your nib to the wrong property. Try selecting the neighbours table in your nib, and then checking your Connections Inspector tab.

[image: Connections Inspector]

Comment: Changed the @property in .h, and double checked the inspector. All looks right, and yet, still empty table.